# averaging multiple scores on small chunks of data or raw score on single collated data

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am using IBM Watson tool to determine tones (https://tone-analyzer-demo.mybluemix.net/) and personality scores (https://personality-insights-livedemo.mybluemix.net/) on different files containing natural language. What would be the recommended strategy and rationale for choosing between:

1. Getting scores from different files and averaging/manipulating them.
2. Getting one raw score on aggregated data and using it.

Comment: I love this question if only to get to know the tools you mentioned. It can be improved by telling your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is 'mood' vs. 'character'. And as such, it depends on the question you ask. E.g. did I make my customer upset? Or is my customer loyal?

Though mood and character correlate, as someone with a certain character will be more likely to be in some mood, there is also variation.

I think you will measure 'mood' with the 'tone' analyzer, and 'character' with the 'personality' analyzer.

For the 'personality' you will need all the data you can get to get the 'average', for the 'mood', a single data point can be sufficient.